# Kinect v2 facetracking - how to get started?

Tags: c#, kinect

I just got my brand new Kinect for Windows v2, I have some programs from the old SDK I would like to port, and from msdn it should be easy. From the samples that comes with the SDK, I feel I have some decent understanding of the new features, I got color, depth and body(the old skeleton) working. Now I just wont to get the facial tracking up running. And here starts my problems.

If I would like the color data:

```
_kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();            
_colorFrameReader = _kinectSensor.ColorFrameSource.OpenReader();
_colorFrameReader.FrameArrived += _colorFrameReader_FrameArrived;
_kinectSensor.Open();
```

If I would like the body data:

```
_bodyFrameReader = _kinectSensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();
bodyFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_FrameArrived;
_kinectSensor.Open();
```

But if I would like to get the face data, I never get the callback:

```
var faceFrameSource = new FaceFrameSource(KinectSensor.GetDefault());
_faceFrameReader = faceFrameSource.OpenReader();
_faceFrameReader.FrameArrived +=_faceFrameReader_FrameArrived;
_kinectSensor.Open();
```

Can anyone help me with how I get face tracking to work in kinect v2 sdk?

Comment: Is my English so bad, or does I need to reformulate my question, please leave a comment instead of just voting it down :)

Comment: have you defined which faceframefeatures should be read ? and the trackingid of the faceframesource should be the bodytrackingid

Comment: @Mark No I haven't added either the bodytrackingId or faceframefeatures. After adding them I got the event, but they didn't got any data. Then I found this post, where I had to do some post build events: http://www.kinectingforwindows.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution based on @Marks comments, and this post: http://www.kinectingforwindows.com/

I first needed to set both the trackingId and the faceframwfeatures, I do this when I get a tracked body:

```
private void bodyFrameReader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataReceived = false;

        using (var bodyFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (bodyFrame != null)
            {
                if (_bodies == null)
                {
                    _bodies = new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount];
                }
                bodyFrame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(_bodies);
                dataReceived = true;
            }
        }

        if (dataReceived)
        {
            foreach (var body in _bodies)
            {
                if(!body.IsTracked)
                    continue;

                if (_player == null)
                    PlayerFound(body);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

PlayTracked sets the _player to the body, and starts the facetracking:

```
private void PlayerFound(Body body)
    {
        _player = body;
        StartFaceTracting(body);
    }
```

And then the tracking is started:

```
private void StartFaceTracting(Body body)
    {
        // Face
        _faceFrameSource = new FaceFrameSource(KinectSensor.GetDefault())
        {
            FaceFrameFeatures = FaceFrameFeatures.BoundingBoxInColorSpace | FaceFrameFeatures.PointsInColorSpace,
            TrackingId = body.TrackingId
        };

        _faceFrameSource.TrackingIdLost += _faceFrameSource_TrackingIdLost;

        _faceFrameReader = _faceFrameSource.OpenReader();
        _faceFrameReader.FrameArrived += _faceFrameReader_FrameArrived;
        Log.Info("Facetracking strated Id: " + body.TrackingId);
    }
```

Then I need on last and very important thing, the post build event, which is to copy the NuiDatabase to the output folder on my installation it's: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.Kinect.Face\2.0\Redist\CommonConfiguration\x64\NuiDatabase":
[image]

After I got the post build events up running, I got data in the FaceFrame :)